# Как правильно применять this в jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как мне правильно записать данную функцию?

```
$('section').each( function(i){
    $(this +" .video").css("opacity", "0");
});
```

Comment: дайте полную функцию

Comment: `$(this).find(".video")` ?

Comment: или сразу `$("section .video").css(....)`

Comment: @teran Спасибо. Первое помогло.

Comment: оформил ответом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` в данном контексте указывает на объект текущей `section`. чтобы найти дочерний элемент, используйте методы `find` или `children` в зависимости от сиутации.

```
 $(this).find(".video");
```

фактически, если это единственное действие, то здесь нет необходимости в цикле и можно использовать код

```
$("section .video").css(....)
```